# Remove hibernated Windows8.1 from Dualboot System with Linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uninstall, hibernate

I have a dual boot system Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / Win8.1.
Windows is hibernated because it stuck up while updating and never got past 100%. I know you can fix that but I just want to get rid of Windows.

Also due to the hibernation, `/dev/sda4`, `/dev/sda5` and anything but the HOME directory in `/dev/sda7` are READ-ONLY.

The partitions:

```
like in gparted:
/dev/sda1 fat32   /boot/efi SYSTEM   100.00 MiB boot
/dev/sda2 ntfs              Recovery 900.00 MiB hidden, diag
/dev/sda3 unknown                    128.00 MiB msftres
/dev/sda4 ntfs              OS       327.60 GiB msftdata
/dev/sda5 ntfs              Data     356.51 GiB msftdata
/dev/sda7 ext4    /                  178.51 GiB
/dev/sda9 unknown                      3.89 GiB
/dev/sda8 unknown                      3.89 GiB
/dev/sda6 ntfs              Restore   15.01 GiB hidden, diag
```

Which of these partitions can I delete to reassign their disk-space and will that solve the READ-ONLY issue?